# JavaScript: TextDecoder on SharedArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, postmessage, uint8array, sharedarraybuffer, textdecoder

I am facing a problem with decode() on SharedArrayBuffer.

**Code:**

```
  var sharedArrayBuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(2);
  var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(sharedArrayBuffer);
  uint8Array[0] = 20;
  var decoder = new TextDecoder();
  decoder.decode(uint8Array);
```

**Error:**

```
Failed to execute 'decode' on 'TextDecoder': The provided ArrayBufferView value must not be shared.
```

There is a specification [here](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-textdecoder-decode) that warns developers about race-condition on this type of memory. Can I somehow force decoding? I am sure data will not be changed during decoding. Or is there a workaround for this?

**Reasons:**
I want to create a single copy of Uint8Array and pass it without copying via postmessage (which copies by default if transferrable is not specified) to several(>3) IFrames(with sandbox tag). Maybe there are other possible solutions?

Comment: Your pages are same-origin anyway, right? So can't you just do `top.globallyAccessibleArrayBuffer` from your frames?

Comment: I am missing something, is there a way IFrame with tag sandbox can access its parents' variables? Or can I ask you to elaborate on your comment(provide any code)?

Comment: You never stated these iframes were sandboxed befire my comment.  How do you make your CO isolation work? With the experimental `allow=cross-origin-isolated` feature policy? Or with `sandbox=allow-same-origin`? Or with something else I'm not aware of? I was under the impression you need same-origin to have SharedArrayBuffer, and thus you'd have access to the various contexts anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the description after your comment, totally missed it when describing the problem. I use "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy" : "same-origin",                    "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy" : "require-corp" in headers of my webpack dev server in order to use SharedArrayBuffer.

Comment: Interesting... What browser are you using? My main one is Firefox and because of it I thought its behavior was the "normal" one, and there, I am unable to load a sandboxed iframe from a cross-origin isolated document, unless it has the "allow-same-origin" sandbox clause. I now see that both Chrome and Safari do allow it though, but then, only in Safari am I able to postMessage an SAB, Chrome failing silently (no error, no message). So given all this it seems that to have a cross-browser behavior you'd need the iframes to be same-origin anyway. But maybe you're targeting only one vendor?

Comment: Actually Chrome does fire a "messageerror" on the iframe when postMessaging the SAB.

Comment: Currently, I am using Chrome and I did not even think that the behavior might be different amongst different browsers, wow. For now, I am still unable to use existing TextDecoder on SAB unless I copy values from SAB to AB (f.e: Uint8Array) and pass it to TextDecoder.decode().

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, today you have to incur the extra buffer + copy in order to consistently do this across browsers.  It's plausible that any given browser may allow this, but it ***isn't portable*** as of writing this.

For context, the ability for `TextDecoder.decode(...)` to take a `SharedArrayBuffer` is desired functionality for WebAssembly and other low-level performance scenarios, but it's stuck in [standards](https://github.com/whatwg/encoding/issues/172) and [implementation-related](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/18034) discussions.

Here's an example of a buffer-intermediate code path that works to bypass this failing today:

```
function decodeFromSharedBuffer(sharedBuffer, maxLength) {
  const decoder = new TextDecoder()
  const copyLength = Math.min(sharedBuffer.byteLength, maxLength)

  // Create a temporary ArrayBuffer and copy the contents of the shared buffer
  // into it.
  const tempBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(copyLength)
  const tempView = new Uint8Array(tempBuffer)

  let sharedView = new Uint8Array(sharedBuffer)
  if (sharedBuffer.byteLength != copyLength) {
    sharedView = sharedView.subarray(0, copyLength)
  }
  tempView.set(sharedView)

  return decoder.decode(tempBuffer)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like using ArrayBuffer works fine.

```
  var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(2);
  var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  uint8Array[0] = 20;
  var decoder = new TextDecoder();
  decoder.decode(uint8Array);
```

Comment: The problem is - I would like then share this memory to IFrames, I do want to evade of structured cloning during postmessage, thus I am using SharedArrayBuffer.

Comment: ah, right. Looks like you have to use Atomics in this case. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics#using_atomics

Comment: Am I right that I have to implement decoding by myself using atomics for SharedArrayBuffer?

Answer (score -2):

Js

```
var sharedArrayBuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(32);
var ary = new Int32Array(sharedArrayBuffer);
ary[0] = 20;
var encoder = new TextEncoder();
var EncodedArray = encoder.encode(ary);
console.log("Encoded Array : ", EncodedArray)
var decoder = new TextDecoder();
var DecodedArray = decoder.decode(EncodedArray);
console.log("Decoded Array is : ", DecodedArray)
```

Comment: Sir, I do not want to encode my SharedArrayBuffer, the data in it is already encoded. I only need to decode it, thanks. Whilst your approach - while encoding it first returns a complete new Uint8Array which is ArrayBuffer underneath and hence can be passed to decode() function later. So, your answer is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).